# How to return an observable in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am following a tutorial where we populate a selection list.

The teacher is using Angular4 and I am using the latest release so I think the API has changed.

I am trying to use this method in a class called CategoryService:

```
getCategories() {return this.db.list('/categories');}
```

and in another class called ProductFormComponent in my constructor I am trying to return an observable that I can catch in HTML

```
categories$;

constructor (
    private router: Router,
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
}
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <select #category="ngModel" ngModel name="category" id="category" class="form-control" required>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.$key">
            {{ c.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="category.touched && category.invalid">
        Category is required.
    </div>
</div>
```

This gives the error

> Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

What is it I'm doing wrong and what would fix this?

Comment: Does the call getCategories return an observable? I believe that’s where your problem resides because you’re trying to apply an async pipe to a non observable.

Comment: Well i am following every step with the instructor, and he says this returns an observable for some reason, but i'm very new to this so i still have a long way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is that your following an old tutorial that is using an old version of the firebase connector.

On the version 5 there are some needed changes.

In your service you would need to do something like this

```
getCategories() {return this.db.list('/categories')
.snapshotChanges()
.pipe(
    map(categories => categories.map(category => ( { key: category.key, ...category.payload.val() } )))
        );}
```

If you want to be able to use a `key` later on (which you also should define in the object)

If you don’t need this you can just use the following option in your service:

```
getCategories() {return this.db.list('/categories').valueChanges()}
```

These options are the new format used on firebase API 5.0 to return an observable. It’s no longer being returned by default as it used to be on version 4.0

For more details on this and on which version would be more appropriate to you check the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md#50) on the changes

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used your solution and now when i select the item from the list and log it in console, it is shown as "undefined" any solution for that? i didn't get any error messages at all...

Comment: Which version did you use? The valueChanges()?

Comment: Well from what I can see in the html template you are using $key. That no longer exists. If you use the snapshotChanges option you can use ‘key’ instead of ‘$key’. You would have [value]=“c.key”. But for using this you need to use the first option I’m showing in my answer. The one that maps the key and the payload from the snapshotChanges. If this solves your problem please don’t forget to set the answer as accepted and upvote so it can help others with similar issues.

Comment: I used the snapshotchanges option and removed the $ sign and it now works! Just one last question: Is there a shorter version than the snapshop method? seems like a long code for such a small task, just asking so i can learn more :)

Comment: Well you have a couple of options. For instance if you don’t want to use the auto-generated ID from firebase you don’t need those steps. You can just use the other option of the valueChanges(). In that case you would need to have your own ‘id’ field with a unique value created by you. So it’s a matter of picking up what works better for you :). I agree it can be a bit verbose but you only write it in one place anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

If `this.db.list()` is not returning an `Observable`, you can use the following:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

class CategoryService {

    getCategories() {
        return of(this.db.list('/categories'));
    }

}
```

This would wrap your data in an observable.

But if the operation is fully synchronous, then there's no reason to use an Observable.

Comment: Sadly this does not work as i am faced with a new error. "Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Comment: The error is very explicit, your service returns a single object while it should return a list of objects.

Comment: Understood. But why is my instructor not getting the same error i am getting? The code is exactly like he wrote in Angular4

Answer (score 0):

Looks like following method is not returning an observable -

```
getCategories() {return this.db.list('/categories');}
```

I think "this.db.list('/categories');" returns a simple array. To ensure getCategories() returns an observable do the following -

```
getCategories() {
  const values = this.db.list('/categories');
  return of(values);
}
```

"of" is a rxjs operator. Import it from "rxjs".
Please note I am assuming that this.db.list('/categories'); is returning simple array.
Ideally, you use HTTP client to call your backend which returns the data wrapped in an observable.